# Requisição de mensagem em arquivo .php

Tags: php, ajax

Criei um formulário de email, está funcional. Só gostaria de saber como retornar a mensagem `echo('Email enviado com sucesso')`. Para dentro do meu index html.

Por exemplo:

```
<form method="POST" action="./email.php"> 
                <label>Digite seu nome:
                   <input id="name" type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Nome" required>
                </label>
<input id="btn_enviar_email" class="send" type="submit">Enviar</input>
```

Ao submeter lógicamente abre em uma nova página com a mensagem de email enviado. Gostaria de retornar esse valor e tratar dentro do meu index. No caso, sem abrir uma nova guia pra isso.

[image: Mensagem de email não enviado.]

Comment: Para não sair da página troque o `<input type="submit">` por um `<input type="button">` com o evento `onClick` apontado para uma função que faça uma requisição ou `JQuery.ajax` ou `XMLHttpRequest` direcionada a `email.php` com os dados do email. Para tratar as mensagens só vendo o código php para dar uma opinião.

Answer (score -1):

Adicione um id ou classe para o seu form para chamar ele em um arquivo JS, no exemplo vou te passar a resolução com Jquery, supondo que seu ID seja enviar-email, pode retirar a action também

```
$('#enviar-email').submit(function (e) {
 $.ajax({
  url: './email.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: new FormData(this),
  dataType: 'json',
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,

  error: function (jsonRetError) {
   console.log(jsonRetError);
  },
  success: function (jsonRetSucess) {
   alert(jsonRetSucess);
  }
});
});
```

Por sua vez no seu arquivo email.php fará da seguinte forma se o e-mail for enviado

```
$retorno['mensagem'] = "E-mail enviado";
echo json_encode($retorno);
```